# Where can one find a list of all the operators in J

Tags: operators, j, tacit-programming

I am trying to learn J and one huge problem I'm running into is I don't know what all the predefined operators are or where to find them.  It took me way too long to figure out the | is both the remainder function(when it dyadic) but when its used monadic it gets absolute value or magnitude.  Does any one know where a list of all the operators that J defines by default could be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for the [J Vocabulary](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/vocabul.htm), although trying to read its documentation on monadic vs. dyadic `|` is greek to me.  (Disclaimer: I am not a J programmer)

Comment: that looks exactly like what I was looking for thanks.  Monadic means it takes in arguments from one side like this +/ 1 2 3 and returning 6 dyadic means taking arguments from both sides 1 2 3 +/ 1 2 3 returnin
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6

Comment: It's really unfortunate that J doesn't have built-in help, using the foreign conjunction I'm sure. One of the things I love about REBOL is that I can type `help foo` and get immediate help on `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

In the J version 6 IDE, control-F1 will bring up documentation on the word at the cursor, if it's defined in the implementation.  Hopefully the new version 7 interfaces will eventually manage to retain this feature.